# Trying to use a python script to manipulate a value from attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, python-parser

I am using ArcGIS ArcMap 10.2 and I am trying to learn how to write a python script to use a value from an attribute table and perform some checks to it and assign an output value. At this moment all I want to do is multiple the input value from the attribute table by 2 and output it. This is as the below screenshot.

[image]

What the error message I get in the result is

```
Executing: CalculateField taranaki_dairy_farms stuff thickness PYTHON_9.3 "thickness = 
!River_ID! * 2"
Start Time: Sun Jun 07 20:34:23 2015
Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000989: Python syntax error: Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 1)
Failed to execute (CalculateField).
Failed at Sun Jun 07 20:34:23 2015 (Elapsed Time: 0.00 seconds)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code block:

```
def times2 (x):
    return x*2
```

Expression:

```
times2 (!river_id!)
```